# Is there a way other than WKT to insert geometry to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, insert, syntax, geometry

I am using design data from *.dwg and *.dgn to insert geometries to SQL Server field which is set to geometry. All examples I see are using something called WKT which is a specification by a company called OGC but they do not offer any converters so not straightforward to convert from *.dwg / *.dgn to prepare the insert statement.

Is there a different way to the WKT syntax to insert into SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't support input from foreign formats. However, you can use GDAL's [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to [convert foreign formats representing Simple Features to a MSSQL import](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29849/6052)

- [**DGN** is supported by the opensource GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dgn.html)
- **DWG** requires [building against Teigha which while open source is not, afaik, free](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42180/6052). However, they provide [a File Converter](https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/TeighaFileConverter). You can find more information about [Teigha fiasco/political situation here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42180/6052), but there is explicit mention of support with Teigha in the GDAL docs,

  > OGR supports reading most versions of AutoCAD DWG when built with the Open Design Alliance Teiga library. DWG is an binary working format used for AutoCAD drawings. A reasonable effort has been made to make the OGR DWG driver work similarly to the OGR DXF driver which shares a common data model. The entire contents of the .dwg file is represented as a single layer named "entities".

More info:

- [Formats GDAL supports our of the box here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_dwg.html)
- [Download a copy of GDAL for proprietary overpriced operating systems here.](http://www.gisinternals.com/)

To ease upgrading in the future to Ubuntu, you can install `ogr2ogr` with only

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```